Are you interested in us moderators posting about activities on Bitcoin.SE?
Would you think a topic on "meta" where we mods and any other users can post about their administrative activities on Bitcoin.SE. each month would be interesting/engaging for the site's users?

What's happening on Bitcoin.SE in May 2015?
  Answers:

This week I introduced blocksize, to collect questions about the discussion on the increase and related topics, and added it to a bunch of posts.
We merged bootstrap.dat and bootstrap
We reworked the [about] page.


It could be featured and may help get more users interested in the moderation of the site.
